# How to define two different routes to the same controller?

Tags: laravel, routes

Is there  way to define the following in a cleaner way?

```
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@home')->name('home');
Route::get('/home', 'SiteController@home');
```

What would be the recommended, most performant Laravel way?

Comment: In this case, you could have `'/'` redirect to `'/home' (or vice versa), so `Route::get('/', function(){ return redirect('/home'); });`. That being said, I don't think there's anything wrong/performance heavy with having both routes accessing the same controller function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to map multiple routes to one controller. Not sure if it looks cleaner, or even 'better'.

```
$router->get('/{home?}', 'SiteController@home')
       ->where('home', '(home|another_home_route)')
       ->name('home');
```

This will work for the routes:

- /
- /home
- /another_home_route

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/{verb?}', 'SiteController@home');
```

And then handle the logic inside the controller function

```
function home($verb = 'empty') {
    if ($verb == 'home') {
         // do home thing
    } else if ($verb == 'empty') {
        // do empty thing
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing section *Optional Parameters*

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8 you can do that:

```
Route::controller(HomeController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'index');
    Route::get('/', 'index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;

Route::controller(ProfileController::class)->group(function () {
  Route::get('/profile/{id}', 'show');
  Route::post('/profile/store', 'store'); 
});
```

Here is the documentation link:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-controllers